# C++: Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'char*' with an lvalue of type 'double' in a template function using type conditional

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I want to write a template function to copy data from one array to another array. I only want to handle `int`, `double` and `char*` (string) arrays in my program.

```
template<typename T>
void copy_key(T *destination, int destination_index, T *source, int source_index){
    if (typeid(T) == typeid(int) or typeid(T) == typeid(double)){
        destination[destination_index] = source[source_index];
    } else {
        // char* case
        strcpy(destination[destination_index], source[source_index]);
    }
}
```

If I call `copy_key()` as below, I will get error :  Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'char*' with an lvalue of type 'double'.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    double from_array[3] = {1.0,2.0,3.0};
    double to_array[3];
    copy_key(to_array, 0, from_array, 2);
    std::cout << to_array[0] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I thought if `T` was `double`, the else block would not be entered. My question is how to correctly use condition on the template type in my example?

Comment: The `else` block still has to be *compiled*. The `if` selection is still done at *run-time*. Also, it looks like some kind of specialization or just plain overload would be a better design I think.

Comment: The function needs to be able to compile as a whole.  If you replaced the template parameter "by-hand" ie created a new stand-alone function (with the template parameter T substituted) would you expect it to compile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I thought if `T` was `double`, the else block would not be entered.

You thought correctly. But your assumption about its consequences are not correct.

Just because some code will not be executed, doesn't mean that it, along with the rest of the program, doesn't need to be well formed.

Even though in this case it might be possible for the compiler to prove that the line will not be executed, such proof is practically impossible for all possible programs in general, so it cannot affect the correctness of the program.

A typical solution is to use either overloads, or template specializations:

```
void copy_key(char *destination, int destination_index, const char *source, int source_index){
    strcpy(...);
}

void copy_key(double *destination, int destination_index, double *source, int source_index){
    destination[destination_index] ...
}
```

In the upcoming C++17, there will be `constexpr if` which allows conditionally compiled blocks within a single function.

Answer (score 3):

In C++17 you will get [`if constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) that only evaluates one branch of the if-statement.

Right now both the if-part and the else-part must be valid code for type `T`. If you want it to behave different for different types, you will have to specialize the template.

Answer (score 3):

In C++14 and before, use [template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) instead of conditionals.

C++ is a compiled language, not interpreted. When a templatized function is being compiled for a particular concrete use, the entire function needs to be compiled, not just the branches that happen to be taken. The compiler in general can't infer the exact path your code will take for all inputs *a priori*.

```
template<typename T>
void copy_key(T *destination, int destination_index, T *source, int source_index){
    destination[destination_index] = source[source_index];
}

template<>
void copy_key(const char** destination, int destination_index, const char** source, int source_index) {
    // char* case
    strcpy(destination[destination_index], source[source_index]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can´t. Put as:

```
template<typename T>
void copy_key(T *destination, int destination_index, T *source, int source_index){
    if (some_condition){ // some_condition met
        destination[destination_index] = source[source_index];
    } else { // some condition not met
        // char* case
        strcpy(destination[destination_index], source[source_index]);
    }
}
```

is easier to see.

You need a "conditional compilation" instead (template specialization)